# A certain property of integral domains $A \subseteq B$ with $Q(A) \cap B= A$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, separable-algebras

I have asked the following question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291220/a-certain-property-of-integral-domains-a-subseteq-b-that-satisfy-qa-cap-b):

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero. Let $A \subseteq B$ be $k$-algebras which are also (commutative) integral domains with fields of fractions $Q(A) \subseteq Q(B)$.
Assume that $Q(A) \cap B=A$.

Define **property $P$** as follows:

*If $w:=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \tilde{a_i} b^i \in B$, where $\tilde{a_i} \in Q(A), b \in B$,
then $b \in A$ or $\tilde{a_i} \in B$ for all $0 \leq i \leq n$.*

By the assumption that $Q(A) \cap B=A$, property $P$ becomes:

*If $w:=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \tilde{a_i} b^i \in B$, where $\tilde{a_i} \in Q(A), b \in B$,
then $b \in A$ or $\tilde{a_i} \in A$ for all $0 \leq i \leq n$.*

> **Question:** When such $A \subseteq B$ satisfies property $P$? Namely, could one find an additional 'mild' condition which guarantees that
> $A \subseteq B$ satisfies property $P$?

**Non-answer:**
The following four conditions do not guarantee that
$A \subseteq B$ satisfies property $P$:

**(i)** $B$ is simple over $A$, namely, $B=A[\hat{b}]$ for some $\hat{b} \in B$.

**(ii)** $B$ is integral over $A$, namely, for every element $b \in B$ there exist
$a_{n-1},\ldots,a_1,a_0 \in A$ such that
$b^n+a_{n-1}b^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1b+a_0=0$.

**(iii)** The invertible elements of $A$ and $B$ are $k^{\times}$ only.

**(iv)** $A \subseteq B$ is flat.

**(v)** Both $A$ and $B$ are UFD's.

Indeed, for example, $A=k[y^2], B=k[y]$, $\tilde{a_1}=\frac{1}{y^2}$, $b=y^3, w=\tilde{a_1}b$; this example appears as an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356663/does-fraca-1a-2-fraca-3a-4b-in-b-qa-cap-b-a-imply-fraca?noredirect=1&lq=1).

**Plausible answers:**

**(1.)** $A \subseteq B$ is a [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_algebra) ring extension? (or separable and flat? Flatness alone is not enough).

**(2.)** $Q(A)=Q(B)$. Indeed, in this case we get
$B=Q(B) \cap B=Q(A) \cap B=A$. Then $b \in B=A$.

**Remarks:**

**(1)** Notice that if $n=0$ then property $P$ is satisfied; indeed,
if $n=0$ then $B \ni w=\tilde{a_0}b^0=\tilde{a_0} \in Q(A)$,
so $\tilde{a_0}= w \in Q(A) \cap B =A$.

**(2)** There is a nice theorem by H. Bass that appears [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=2n7kBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=differential%20structure%20of%20etale&source=bl&ots=CwQzAR6_t_&sig=rj20DhcGt_XYgc-SZABpYbgbmis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSypnWjILUAhVGWxQKHSHxDs0Q6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=differential%20structure%20of%20etale&f=false) (Remark after Corollary 1.3, page 74); it presents conditions on two integral domains $A \subseteq B$ implying that $Q(A) \cap B=A$, but here I am assuming that this equality is satisfied.

Thank you very much for any hints and comments!

Comment: Do you want to say $a_i \in B$ for *all* $i$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, thank you. Yes, I want to say that $\tilde{a_i} \in B$ for all $i$ (or $b \in A$). I now edited my question.

Comment: I have now found a partial answer to a special case of my question, namely the case where $n \leq 1$ (I suspect that a similar argument holds for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$): If $A,B$ are both UFD's and every irreducible element of $A$ remains irreducible in $B$, then property $P$ is satisfied. Perhaps I will later add the argument.